# Java Android, Whats going on here when we are setting up a listener for checkbox? How does the syntax work here?

Tags: java, android, listener

Can someone explain the syntax to me?

```
mSolvedCheckBox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.crime_solved);
    mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // Set the crime's solved property
            mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

Also I'm finding it a bit tough to understand android following the big nerd ranch guide book. I know some java basics like object oriented programming, classes, polymorphism, constructors, encapsulation all those things but seems like my knowledge isn't enough.

From where should I study more Java to fill in the gaps?

Comment: what is this mCrime ??

Comment: is there anything wrong with the intended behavior or you just need some tips on what the functions are doing?

Comment: I am guessing you are following Big Nerd Ranch's android guide. If I recall correctly, mCrime is an object in your CrimeLab. The above code is setting a boolean variable isSolved in mCrime object when user clicks on mSolvedCheckBox in your fragment.

Comment: What exactly is not understood by you? what is a problem?

Comment: the answer answered it nvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study about [Anonymous classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) in Java.

```
mSolvedCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // Set the crime's solved property
            mCrime.setSolved(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

Here, you are passing an object of Anonymous class implementing the `OnCheckedChangeListener` interface.